# Mysql Randomise Rows for Quiz

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table structure:

> Id Question Answer1 Answer2 Answer3 Answer4

Answer1 is always the correct answer, so I'd like to be able to display the four Answers in a random order using PHP.

How would this be possible?

Comment: This is a little bit outside of your question, but i think that your table structure is a little bit problematic. I would have one table with questions and one with answers. Then you could have as many answers per question as you want, and it would be easier to shuffle your answers.

Comment: The way my system is created, there are only ever meant to be 4 answers to each question, no less, no more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using php `shuffle` function like this,:

First you create an array of answers `$answers` then you shuffle this array `shuffle($answers);`

```
   $query=mysqli_query($db_conn, "SELECT Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4 FROM questions_table WHERE id=1");

   $array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
   $question=$array['Question'];
   $answers=array($array['Answer1'], $array['Answer2'], $array['Answer3'], $array['Answer4']);
   shuffle($answers);
```

Answer (score 3):

Put Answers into array, and than shuffle array using: `shuffle`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest getting results into array and then shuffle them with the following code (if you're using prepared statements, and you better use them):

```
$SQL = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id");
$SQL -> execute(array(':id' => $id));

$results = $SQL -> fetch();
$question = $results['question'];

$answers = array($results['answer1'],$results['answer2'],$results['answer3'],$results['answer4'];

shuffle($answers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You table structure will make management of the database a huge problem in future.
With your present design, select your questions normally then place answers in an array and then `shuffle($answers)` will shuffle the answers.
**Correct Solution** will be to normalize your database, separate `answers` from `questions`. Use question_id to link questions to their answers. It will make your database design very flexible and management will be a lot easier.

Comment: Please read the question again. He didn't want to shuffle the question, but the answers and the answers is in the 4 last columns

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this with MYSQL because the answers are all in the same row. As ThePixelPony you should use the `shuffle` function in PHP